# Show that if $n$ and $m$ are both positive, then $nm$ is positive.

Tags: real-analysis, natural-numbers

This problem is on Terrence Tao's Analysis I, page 36.

> Let $n,m$ be natural numbers. Then $n \times m=0$ if and only if atleast one of $n,m$ is equal to zero. In particular, if $n$ and $m$ are both positive, then $nm$ is also positive.

I know that multiplication is defined as recursive addition. $1 \times m := m$ and $(n+1) \times m= (n \times m) + m$. But, that's all that comes to my mind. I am not sure, how to find and organize my arguments to prove the above result. Should I use induction? Any hints, tips that lead me to prove this result would be helpful.

As a second question, what's a reasonable amount of time, I should spend on thinking about a theorem and sketching a proof, before I move on, perhaps try another question and then come back later? And should I search for a solution on the Internet, if I still don't get it.

Comment: I haven't read Tao (although I feel like I should because he seems to generate more questions than Rudin), but in order to answer the question you'll also have to work in Tao's definition of "positive".  What is that?

Comment: A natural number $n$ is said to be positive if and only if $n$ is not equal to zero.

Comment: Okay, so it seems like you can make a lemma showing that the sum of two positive numbers is positive and then that the product of two positive numbers is positive by induction on the recursive definitions of addition and multiplication.

Comment: @MatthewDaly, let me try that approach and see if I can sketch some proof. Any tips for my second question.. ?

Answer (score 1):

*Proof(Rough sketch)*.

Let $n,m$ be positive natural numbers. We induct on $n$ keeping $m$ fixed.

(I) Claim. $1 \times m$ is positive. 
$1 \times m := m$ by the definition of multiplication and $m$ is positive.

(II) We inductively assume that $n \times m$ is positive.

(III) We would like to show that $(n+1)\times m$ is positive.

By the definition of multiplication:

$\begin{aligned}
(n+1) \times m &= (n \times m) + m
\end{aligned}$

$n \times m$ is positive from the inductive assumption. $m$ is a positive natural number. The sum of two positive natural numbers is a positive number. This closes the induction.